# Rails GeoIP County Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geoip

Does anyone know if there's a free county GeoIP database out there? I've been looking around but haven't had much luck. Basically my client wants to be able to target folks by zip code and by county. So far I've found zip but not county.

Comment: by 'target' you mean to get their zipcode based on their ip? Is this what you need?

Comment: Well I have a database that gives them their zip code, more so just need one that has county's by their IP. But yes, basically they want to offer certain things based on where the user is located based on their IP.

Comment: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: I'll check this out, looks like it will have the info we need by county!